# Getting information from multidimensional arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I posted this issue a few weeks ago, and got some excellent feedback but I didn't post my question clearly and wasn't able to get an answer to solve the problem.  So, I'm redoing this post and trying again.

However, php dosn't have good functions for working with deep multidimensional arrays and that makes this difficult (but not impossible!), And most likely this is due to the choices I made in formatting my array to be human readable as opposed to making it "flatter" and easier to handle by code.

All my source code is available via Github: https://github.com/mudgw2/dungeon-generator3

The Problem
I have a random dungeon generator thats producing very rich data and very nested data from various json source files.  The array is DYNAMIC so its structure changes, however there are keys which do NOT change (each array in the multidimensional array has an uid generated for it).

So my array looks a bit like this:

```
{"uid":"5796615f0c12c","intro":"While traveling in the wilderness, the characters fall into a sinkhole that opens beneath their feet, dropping them into the adventure location.","goal":"Retrieve a stolen item hidden in the dungeon.","starting_area":{"desc":"Circle, 40ft. diameter; one passage at each cardinal direction","width":40,"length":40,"height":10,"shape":"circle","passages":"N,E,W","doors":"S","tile":"starting_area_006.png","id":6,"uid":"5796615f0c48e","N":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., comes to a dead end.","width":10,"length":20,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":10,"doors":"S","tile":"passage_006.png","id":6,"secret":{"chance":15,"description":"No hidden doors found."},"uid":"5796615f0c974","from_uid":"5796615f0c48e","S":{"desc":"Wooden","width":5,"length":1,"height":10,"barred":0,"locked":0,"secret":0,"shape":"","tile":"","id":1,"uid":"5796615f0d04c","direction":"S"}},"E":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., then the passage turns right and continues 10ft.","width":10,"length":20,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_008.png","id":8,"uid":"5796615f0d155","from_uid":"5796615f0c48e"},"W":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., side passage to the left, then an additional 10ft. ahead","width":10,"length":40,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"E","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_005.png","id":5,"uid":"5796615f0da1d","from_uid":"5796615f0c48e"}},"5796615f0e422":{"content":{"content":"Trap (see 'Random Traps')","monster":0,"treasure":0,"trap":1,"id":7},"desc":"Chapel where the lair's inhabitants worship","doors":"","height":10,"id":6,"length":0,"passages":"S","purpose":"Trap designed to kill or capture creatures","shape":"square","state":"Holes, floor partially collapsed","tile":"chamber_006.png","uid":"5796615f0e520","width":0,"S":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., comes to a dead end.","width":10,"length":20,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_009.png","id":9,"uid":"5796615f0ffc7","from_uid":"5796615f0e520"}},"5796615f10c68":{"content":{"content":"Monster (random creature)","monster":1,"treasure":0,"trap":0,"id":5},"desc":"Kennel for pets or guard beasts","doors":"E","height":10,"id":9,"length":0,"monster":[{"name":"giant weasel","size":"M","rarity":"common","cr":1,"xp":400,"ac":15,"touch-ac":14,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":9,"FORT":3,"REF":7,"WILL":1,"init":4,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":5,"melee_dmg":"1d6+3","Str":14,"Dex":19,"Con":10,"Int":2,"Wis":13,"Cha":11,"environments":"land","treasure":0,"desc":"The predatory nature of this wolf-sized creature is revealed by its long teeth, sleekly muscular body, and belligerent hiss.","info":"<p>Like their smaller cousins, giant weasels have long, slender bodies and short legs, and come in a variety of colors from reddish brown to snowy white.<\/p>Giant weasels are active and tenacious predators, and have a reputation for being as clever as they are quick. Both highly aggressive and extremely territorial, they frequently attack creatures that are much larger than they are.<p>Giant weasels are often trained to serve as guards and mounts by various Small humanoids. Adult giant weasels can grow to be 5 feet long, stand as high as 2-1\/2 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh up to 150 pounds.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/weasel\/weasel-giant","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":2}],"passages":"","purpose":"Trap designed to kill or capture creatures","shape":"square","state":"Ashes, contents mostly burned","tile":"chamber_009.png","uid":"5796615f10d6b","width":0},"5796615f13e3e":{"content":{"content":"Empty Room with treasure","monster":0,"treasure":1,"trap":0,"id":10},"desc":"Kennel for pets or guard beasts","doors":"E","height":10,"id":9,"length":0,"passages":"","purpose":"Room containing a puzzle that must be solved to bypass a trap or monster","shape":"square","state":"Pristine and in original state","tile":"chamber_009.png","uid":"5796615f13f52","width":0},"5796615f14131":{"content":{"content":"Monster (pet or allied creature) guarding treasure","monster":1,"treasure":1,"trap":0,"id":4},"desc":"Cistern or well for drinking water","doors":"S","from_uid":"5796615f0e3f5","height":10,"id":7,"length":0,"monster":[{"name":"kobold","size":"S","rarity":"common","cr":0.25,"xp":100,"ac":15,"touch-ac":12,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":5,"FORT":2,"REF":1,"WILL":-1,"init":0,"melee":"spear","melee_hit":1,"melee_dmg":"1d6-1\/x3","Str":9,"Dex":13,"Con":10,"Int":10,"Wis":9,"Cha":8,"environments":"temperate,underground,deep forest","treasure":0,"desc":"Short, reptilian humanoid has scaled skin, a snout filled with tiny teeth, and a long tail.","info":"<p>Kobolds are creatures of the dark, found most commonly in enormous underground warrens or the dark corners of the forest where the sun is unable to reach. <\/p><p>Due to their physical similarities, kobolds loudly proclaim themselves the scions of dragonkind, destined to rule the earth beneath the wings of their great god-cousins, but most dragons have little use for the obnoxious pests.<\/p><p>While they may speak loudly of divine right and manifest destiny, kobolds are keenly aware of their own weakness. Cowards and schemers, they never fight fair if they can help it, instead setting up ambushes and double-crosses, holing up in their warrens behind countless crude but ingenious traps, or rolling over the enemy in vast, yipping hordes.<\/p><p>Kobold coloration varies even among siblings from the same egg clutch, ranging through the colors of the chromatic dragons, with red being the most common but white, green, blue, and black kobolds not unheard of.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/humanoids\/kobold","wiki_url":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Kobold_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)","img_url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/_\/rsrc\/1452829556123\/images\/kobold.png","age":13,"alignment":"LE","job":"warrior","id":3},{"name":"bat","size":"D","rarity":"common","cr":0.125,"xp":50,"ac":16,"touch-ac":16,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":2,"FORT":0,"REF":4,"WILL":2,"init":2,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":6,"melee_dmg":"1d3-5","Str":1,"Dex":15,"Con":6,"Int":2,"Wis":14,"Cha":5,"environments":"temperate,forests,deserts","treasure":0,"desc":"","info":"Most bats are insectivores or fruit-eaters, but at least one species drinks blood.","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/bat\/bat","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":1},{"name":"giant weasel","size":"M","rarity":"common","cr":1,"xp":400,"ac":15,"touch-ac":14,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":9,"FORT":3,"REF":7,"WILL":1,"init":4,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":5,"melee_dmg":"1d6+3","Str":14,"Dex":19,"Con":10,"Int":2,"Wis":13,"Cha":11,"environments":"land","treasure":0,"desc":"The predatory nature of this wolf-sized creature is revealed by its long teeth, sleekly muscular body, and belligerent hiss.","info":"<p>Like their smaller cousins, giant weasels have long, slender bodies and short legs, and come in a variety of colors from reddish brown to snowy white.<\/p>Giant weasels are active and tenacious predators, and have a reputation for being as clever as they are quick. Both highly aggressive and extremely territorial, they frequently attack creatures that are much larger than they are.<p>Giant weasels are often trained to serve as guards and mounts by various Small humanoids. Adult giant weasels can grow to be 5 feet long, stand as high as 2-1\/2 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh up to 150 pounds.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/weasel\/weasel-giant","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":2}],"passages":"","purpose":"Kennel for pets or guard beasts","shape":"square","state":"Stripped bare","tile":"chamber_007.png","uid":"5796615f14223","width":0},"5796615f16bc4":{"content":{"content":"Empty Room with treasure","monster":0,"treasure":1,"trap":0,"id":10},"desc":"Kitchen for food storage and preparation","doors":"","height":10,"id":10,"length":0,"passages":"N,S","purpose":"Guardroom fortified against intruders","shape":"square","state":"Ashes, contents mostly burned","tile":"chamber_010.png","uid":"5796615f16cb0","width":0,"N":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., side passage to the left, then an additional 10ft. ahead","width":10,"length":40,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"E","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_005.png","id":5,"uid":"5796615f1c57e","from_uid":"5796615f16cb0"},"S":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., door to the right, then an additional 10 ft. ahead","width":10,"length":35,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"E","tile":"passage_002.png","id":2,"uid":"5796615f1f03c","from_uid":"5796615f16cb0","E":{"desc":"Stone","width":5,"length":1,"height":10,"barred":1,"locked":0,"secret":0,"shape":"","tile":"","id":5,"uid":"5796615f222d9","direction":"E"}}},"5796615f22323":{"content":{"content":"Empty Room with treasure","monster":0,"treasure":1,"trap":0,"id":10},"desc":"Banquet room for important celebrations","doors":"","height":10,"id":3,"length":0,"passages":"N,S,E,W","purpose":"Guardroom fortified against intruders","shape":"square","state":"Stripped bare","tile":"chamber_003.png","uid":"5796615f2240d","width":0},"5796615f226b8":{"content":{"content":"Monster (pet or allied creature)","monster":1,"treasure":0,"trap":0,"id":3},"desc":"Torture chamber","doors":"N","from_uid":"5796615f13e13","height":10,"id":14,"length":0,"monster":[{"name":"giant weasel","size":"M","rarity":"common","cr":1,"xp":400,"ac":15,"touch-ac":14,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":9,"FORT":3,"REF":7,"WILL":1,"init":4,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":5,"melee_dmg":"1d6+3","Str":14,"Dex":19,"Con":10,"Int":2,"Wis":13,"Cha":11,"environments":"land","treasure":0,"desc":"The predatory nature of this wolf-sized creature is revealed by its long teeth, sleekly muscular body, and belligerent hiss.","info":"<p>Like their smaller cousins, giant weasels have long, slender bodies and short legs, and come in a variety of colors from reddish brown to snowy white.<\/p>Giant weasels are active and tenacious predators, and have a reputation for being as clever as they are quick. Both highly aggressive and extremely territorial, they frequently attack creatures that are much larger than they are.<p>Giant weasels are often trained to serve as guards and mounts by various Small humanoids. Adult giant weasels can grow to be 5 feet long, stand as high as 2-1\/2 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh up to 150 pounds.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/weasel\/weasel-giant","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":2}],"passages":"","purpose":"Trap designed to kill or capture creatures","shape":"square","state":"Stripped bare","tile":"chamber_014.png","uid":"5796615f22dfe","width":0},"5796615f2b3da":{"content":{"content":"Trap (see 'Random Traps') protecting treasure","monster":0,"treasure":1,"id":8},"desc":"Training and exercise room","doors":"","height":10,"id":15,"length":0,"passages":"E,W","purpose":"Vault for holding important treasures, accessible only by locked or secret door (75 percent chance of being trapped)","shape":"square","state":"Pristine and in original state","tile":"chamber_015.png","uid":"5796615f2b715","width":0,"E":{"desc":"Stairs","width":10,"length":20,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_010.png","id":10,"uid":"5796615f4013c","from_uid":"5796615f2b715"},"W":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., side passage to the right. then an additional 10ft. ahead","width":10,"length":40,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"E,W","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_004.png","id":4,"uid":"5796615f4637f","from_uid":"5796615f2b715"}},"5796615f4bc98":{"content":{"content":"Monster (random creature) with treasure","monster":1,"treasure":1,"trap":0,"id":6},"desc":"Barracks where the lair's defenders are quartered","doors":"E,W","height":10,"id":4,"length":0,"monster":[{"name":"bat","size":"D","rarity":"common","cr":0.125,"xp":50,"ac":16,"touch-ac":16,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":2,"FORT":0,"REF":4,"WILL":2,"init":2,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":6,"melee_dmg":"1d3-5","Str":1,"Dex":15,"Con":6,"Int":2,"Wis":14,"Cha":5,"environments":"temperate,forests,deserts","treasure":0,"desc":"","info":"Most bats are insectivores or fruit-eaters, but at least one species drinks blood.","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/bat\/bat","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":1},{"name":"kobold","size":"S","rarity":"common","cr":0.25,"xp":100,"ac":15,"touch-ac":12,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":5,"FORT":2,"REF":1,"WILL":-1,"init":0,"melee":"spear","melee_hit":1,"melee_dmg":"1d6-1\/x3","Str":9,"Dex":13,"Con":10,"Int":10,"Wis":9,"Cha":8,"environments":"temperate,underground,deep forest","treasure":0,"desc":"Short, reptilian humanoid has scaled skin, a snout filled with tiny teeth, and a long tail.","info":"<p>Kobolds are creatures of the dark, found most commonly in enormous underground warrens or the dark corners of the forest where the sun is unable to reach. <\/p><p>Due to their physical similarities, kobolds loudly proclaim themselves the scions of dragonkind, destined to rule the earth beneath the wings of their great god-cousins, but most dragons have little use for the obnoxious pests.<\/p><p>While they may speak loudly of divine right and manifest destiny, kobolds are keenly aware of their own weakness. Cowards and schemers, they never fight fair if they can help it, instead setting up ambushes and double-crosses, holing up in their warrens behind countless crude but ingenious traps, or rolling over the enemy in vast, yipping hordes.<\/p><p>Kobold coloration varies even among siblings from the same egg clutch, ranging through the colors of the chromatic dragons, with red being the most common but white, green, blue, and black kobolds not unheard of.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/humanoids\/kobold","wiki_url":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Kobold_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)","img_url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/_\/rsrc\/1452829556123\/images\/kobold.png","age":13,"alignment":"LE","job":"warrior","id":3},{"name":"giant weasel","size":"M","rarity":"common","cr":1,"xp":400,"ac":15,"touch-ac":14,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":9,"FORT":3,"REF":7,"WILL":1,"init":4,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":5,"melee_dmg":"1d6+3","Str":14,"Dex":19,"Con":10,"Int":2,"Wis":13,"Cha":11,"environments":"land","treasure":0,"desc":"The predatory nature of this wolf-sized creature is revealed by its long teeth, sleekly muscular body, and belligerent hiss.","info":"<p>Like their smaller cousins, giant weasels have long, slender bodies and short legs, and come in a variety of colors from reddish brown to snowy white.<\/p>Giant weasels are active and tenacious predators, and have a reputation for being as clever as they are quick. Both highly aggressive and extremely territorial, they frequently attack creatures that are much larger than they are.<p>Giant weasels are often trained to serve as guards and mounts by various Small humanoids. Adult giant weasels can grow to be 5 feet long, stand as high as 2-1\/2 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh up to 150 pounds.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/weasel\/weasel-giant","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":2}],"passages":"","purpose":"Vault for holding important treasures, accessible only by locked or secret door (75 percent chance of being trapped)","shape":"square","state":"Furniture wrecked but stil l present","tile":"chamber_004.png","uid":"5796615f4bf03","width":0},"5796615f5ca87":{"content":{"content":"Empty Room","monster":0,"treasure":0,"trap":0,"id":9},"desc":"Throne room where the lair's leaders hold court","doors":"","height":10,"id":13,"length":0,"passages":"S","purpose":"Trap designed to kill or capture creatures","shape":"square","state":"Pristine and in original state","tile":"chamber_013.png","uid":"5796615f5cb95","width":0,"S":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., door to the left, then an additional 10 ft. ahead","width":10,"length":35,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"E","tile":"passage_003.png","id":3,"uid":"5796615f78c52","from_uid":"5796615f5cb95","E":{"desc":"Wooden","width":5,"length":1,"height":10,"barred":1,"locked":0,"secret":0,"shape":"","tile":"","id":2,"uid":"5796615f82df7","direction":"E"}}},"5796615f82e5f":{"content":{"content":"Monster (pet or allied creature)","monster":1,"treasure":0,"trap":0,"id":3},"desc":"Training and exercise room","doors":"","height":10,"id":15,"length":0,"monster":[{"name":"bat","size":"D","rarity":"common","cr":0.125,"xp":50,"ac":16,"touch-ac":16,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":2,"FORT":0,"REF":4,"WILL":2,"init":2,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":6,"melee_dmg":"1d3-5","Str":1,"Dex":15,"Con":6,"Int":2,"Wis":14,"Cha":5,"environments":"temperate,forests,deserts","treasure":0,"desc":"","info":"Most bats are insectivores or fruit-eaters, but at least one species drinks blood.","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/bat\/bat","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":1},{"name":"kobold","size":"S","rarity":"common","cr":0.25,"xp":100,"ac":15,"touch-ac":12,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":5,"FORT":2,"REF":1,"WILL":-1,"init":0,"melee":"spear","melee_hit":1,"melee_dmg":"1d6-1\/x3","Str":9,"Dex":13,"Con":10,"Int":10,"Wis":9,"Cha":8,"environments":"temperate,underground,deep forest","treasure":0,"desc":"Short, reptilian humanoid has scaled skin, a snout filled with tiny teeth, and a long tail.","info":"<p>Kobolds are creatures of the dark, found most commonly in enormous underground warrens or the dark corners of the forest where the sun is unable to reach. <\/p><p>Due to their physical similarities, kobolds loudly proclaim themselves the scions of dragonkind, destined to rule the earth beneath the wings of their great god-cousins, but most dragons have little use for the obnoxious pests.<\/p><p>While they may speak loudly of divine right and manifest destiny, kobolds are keenly aware of their own weakness. Cowards and schemers, they never fight fair if they can help it, instead setting up ambushes and double-crosses, holing up in their warrens behind countless crude but ingenious traps, or rolling over the enemy in vast, yipping hordes.<\/p><p>Kobold coloration varies even among siblings from the same egg clutch, ranging through the colors of the chromatic dragons, with red being the most common but white, green, blue, and black kobolds not unheard of.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/humanoids\/kobold","wiki_url":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Kobold_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)","img_url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/_\/rsrc\/1452829556123\/images\/kobold.png","age":13,"alignment":"LE","job":"warrior","id":3},{"name":"bat","size":"D","rarity":"common","cr":0.125,"xp":50,"ac":16,"touch-ac":16,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":2,"FORT":0,"REF":4,"WILL":2,"init":2,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":6,"melee_dmg":"1d3-5","Str":1,"Dex":15,"Con":6,"Int":2,"Wis":14,"Cha":5,"environments":"temperate,forests,deserts","treasure":0,"desc":"","info":"Most bats are insectivores or fruit-eaters, but at least one species drinks blood.","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/bat\/bat","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":1},{"name":"giant weasel","size":"M","rarity":"common","cr":1,"xp":400,"ac":15,"touch-ac":14,"flat-footed-ac":14,"hp":9,"FORT":3,"REF":7,"WILL":1,"init":4,"melee":"bite","melee_hit":5,"melee_dmg":"1d6+3","Str":14,"Dex":19,"Con":10,"Int":2,"Wis":13,"Cha":11,"environments":"land","treasure":0,"desc":"The predatory nature of this wolf-sized creature is revealed by its long teeth, sleekly muscular body, and belligerent hiss.","info":"<p>Like their smaller cousins, giant weasels have long, slender bodies and short legs, and come in a variety of colors from reddish brown to snowy white.<\/p>Giant weasels are active and tenacious predators, and have a reputation for being as clever as they are quick. Both highly aggressive and extremely territorial, they frequently attack creatures that are much larger than they are.<p>Giant weasels are often trained to serve as guards and mounts by various Small humanoids. Adult giant weasels can grow to be 5 feet long, stand as high as 2-1\/2 feet tall at the shoulder, and weigh up to 150 pounds.<\/p>","url":"http:\/\/www.d20pfsrd.com\/bestiary\/monster-listings\/animals\/weasel\/weasel-giant","wiki_url":"","img_url":"","age":0,"alignment":"N","job":"","id":2}],"passages":"E,W","purpose":"Antechamber or waiting room for spectators","shape":"square","state":"Ashes, contents mostly burned","tile":"chamber_015.png","uid":"5796615f83005","width":0,"E":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., door to the left, then an additional 10 ft. ahead","width":10,"length":35,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"E","tile":"passage_003.png","id":3,"uid":"5796615f94287","from_uid":"5796615f83005","E":{"desc":"Stone","width":5,"length":1,"height":10,"barred":1,"locked":0,"secret":0,"shape":"","tile":"","id":5,"uid":"5796615f9c71d","direction":"E"}},"W":{"desc":"Continue straight 30ft., no doors or side passages","width":10,"length":30,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"","secret_chance":0,"doors":"","tile":"passage_001.png","id":1,"uid":"5796615f9c819","from_uid":"5796615f83005"}}}
```

With this data, I'm hoping to be able to develop a function where I can pass a UID value and get all the information in that array segment.  When generating the dungeon I'm looking up by UID, then checking sibling keys (which do not change, ie passages and doors), to see if there are any and generate those.

Ultimately, the program is going over the array and generating content thats missing until all are satisfied.

To allow me to work with the array(which saves at the end as json to a file), I have several functions that generate things, and then two functions that find data in the array (which is my issue), and a function to insert into the array (which works if given a proper path).

**Searching Dynamic Multidimensional Array** (give it the array, and UID key and return the entire array segment that matches)

```
function search($arr, $key){
$ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$results = [];
foreach ($ritit as $leafValue) {
$path = [];
foreach (range(0, $ritit->getDepth()) as $depth) {
    $path[] = $ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->key();
}
    $results[] = join('_', $path);
}
array_pop($path);
return $path;}
```

**Inserting into the Array** (given the $path to the location returned by the search, the array that its to insert into the multidimensional array, and the label that the array gets when added)

```
function insert_into_array($path,$a2,$label){
$dest = &$_SESSION['dungeon'];
foreach($path as $pathSegment) {
    $dest = &$dest[$pathSegment];
}
$dest[$label] = $a2;
return true;}
```

Hopefully this better explains the issue.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: How much control do you have over the structure of the data? The UID seems like a good candidate to be a key, rather than just another element in the set.

Comment: I have total control over all of it, its just a personal project of mine for learning.  UID is just a way to provide unique IDs for stuff so I can target parts of the array (as Im having trouble with here), I was trying to make this human readable, and its proving to be harder this way.

Comment: Your right, and I tried to fix it but had trouble.  my project is actually on github: https://github.com/mudgw2/dungeon-generator3/  with full data files.  I hope to redo this entry and clarify that my data is dynamic so I need a flexible way of finding data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best possible way out here is to get the json formatted to an array by using json_decode()

```
$array = json_decode($json_string) // Considering json_string holds your json array
```

Then loop through the array and check if uid matches your desired value and then fetch the result if it matches

Something like this might help

```
$array[$i]->starting_area[$j]->N[$k]->passage
```

might give you the desired values

Comment: This isnt targeting by uid which is required due to the dynamic nature of my array, "starting_area" is only one part of the array, further parts get UIDs for their segment.  So this solution is too rigid for my needs, I think!

Answer (score 0):

First, you may need to check the `json` String you posted... It may not have been properly formatted or some parts of it may have not been copied & pasted properly. In any case, the data was reconstructed for use in this Post.

With that observation out of the way; below is a commented Function to help you do just that... (**Return the value of "passages" where uid = 5790de65145bc**). The function takes 2 Arguments. The 1st Argument is the `JSON String` and the 2nd Argument is the `uid` You want to get the Passages for. You may as well want to test it out [here](https://eval.in/609582).

```
<?php

    // THIS MUST BE A JSON STRING... NOT AN ARRAY OR PHP OBJECT...
    // HOWEVER, IF YOU ARE GENERATING AN A PHP OBJECT (AND NOT JSON STRING)
    // THE FUNCTION WOULD STILL WORK BUT YOU HAVE TO 
    // SIMPLY NOT DO A json_decode WITHIN THE FUNCTION
    $strJson    = '{"uid":"5790de6513913","intro":"While traveling in the wilderness, the characters fall into a sinkhole that opens beneath their feet, dropping them into the adventure location.","goal":"Retrieve a stolen item hidden in the dungeon.","starting_area":{"desc":"Circle, 40ft. diameter; one passage at each cardinal direction","width":40,"length":40,"height":10,"shape":"circle","passages":"N,E,W","doors":"S","tile":"starting_area_006.png","id":6,"uid":"5790de6513da8","N":{"passage":{"desc":"Continue straight 20ft., comes to a dead end.","width":10,"length":20,"height":10,"shape":"","passages":"211","secret_chance":10,"doors":"S","tile":"passage_006.png","id":6,"uid":"5790de65145bc","from_uid":"5790de6513da8","secret":{"chance":15,"description":"No hidden doors found."}}}}}';

    $iPassages  = getPassagesByUID($strJson, "5790de65145bc");

    var_dump($iPassages);     //<== DISPLAYS:: int 211


    function getPassagesByUID($jsonString, $uid){
        // DECODE/CONVERT THE $jsonString INTO A PHP OBJECT.
        // IF $jsonString IS ALREADY A PHP OBJECT, YOU DON'T HAVE TO json_decode IT;
        // INSTEAD THE LINE BELOW SHOULD READ:
        // $objJson = $jsonString;  //SO BE CAREFUL WHAT YOU PASS IN ;-)
        $objJson    = json_decode($jsonString);

        // LOOP THROUGH ALL THE ENTRIES IN THE JSON OBJECT
        foreach($objJson as $key=>$data){
            // CHECK IF THE PROPERTY IS starting_area
            // (SINCE starting_area CONTAINS THE N OBJECT WHICH CONTAINS  THE PASSAGE OBJECT)
            if($key == "starting_area"){
                // IF THAT IS THE CASE, GET THE passage OBJECT & STORE IT IN A VARIABLE
                $passage = $data->N->passage;
                // CHECK IF THE PROPERTY passages EXIST ON THIS PASSAGE OBJECT
                // AND THAT THE uid PROPERTY MATCHES THE $uid GIVEN AS A PARAMETER
                if(property_exists($passage, "passages") && $passage->uid == $uid){
                    // IF IT DOES, RETURN THE VALUE THEREOF
                    return $passage->passages;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**A VALID JSON STRING SHOULD LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:**

```
<?php

    $jsonString = '{
        "uid"           : "5790de6513913",
        "intro"         : "While traveling in the wilderness, the characters fall into a sinkhole that opens beneath their feet, dropping them into the adventure location.",
        "goal"          : "Retrieve a stolen item hidden in the dungeon.",
        "starting_area" : {
            "desc"      : "Circle, 40ft. diameter; one passage at each cardinal direction",
            "width"     : 40,
            "length"    : 40,
            "height"    : 10,
            "shape"     : "circle",
            "passages"  : "N,E,W",
            "doors"     : "S",
            "tile"      : "starting_area_006.png",
            "id"        : 6,
            "uid"       : "5790de6513da8",
            "N"         : {
                "passage": {
                    "desc"          : "Continue straight 20ft., comes to a dead end.",
                    "width"         : 10,
                    "length"        : 20,
                    "height"        : 10,
                    "shape"         : "",
                    "passages"      : "211",
                    "secret_chance" : 10,
                    "doors"         : "S",
                    "tile"          : "passage_006.png",
                    "id"            : 6,
                    "uid"           : "5790de65145bc",
                    "from_uid"      : "5790de6513da8",
                    "secret"        : {
                        "chance"        : 15,
                        "description"   : "No hidden doors found."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }';
```

Notice that it is surrounded by single quote marks and thus it is a string.... Your generated JSON should look like that... if your data is an array or object and you want to convert it to JSON Format, you could use: `json_encode($arrayOrObject);`

Comment: The json is valid (I use jsonlint and internal json checkers to validate the formatting of my external json data), I may have posted a bad snippet...(most likely).  I will try your sample and respond ASAP thanks!!

Comment: $iPassages  = getPassagesByUID($_SESSION['dungeon'], $GenerateQueue[0]);  where $GenerateQueue[0] = 5790de65145bc and $_SESSION['dungeon'] is the above array, returns null.  When I echo the $key values being returned I get: uid
intro
goal
starting_area  - its not going into the array its only staying at the surface level...  :-(

Comment: @DavidWhite Will take a look at it one more time... saw now where the issue might be

Comment: @DavidWhite   Check it again however, be very careful that the `generated JSON Data` is not **RAW** but instead a `JSON String` otherwise it won't work.... anyways; you may as well test it here: https://eval.in/609582

Comment: trying it out, producing some notices and 1 fatal..lemme adjust it a bit. Dosn't like:  $passage = $data->N->passage;  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object, I'll try to tweak this.  Oh and I remove the json decodes as I dont need that as my data is a $_SESSION array at this time.  I shouldn't have said json data...as its not at this stage.

Comment: @DavidWhite   Think the problem is that you are passing a Raw Object  or Array instead of real JSON String.... try this first: `var_dump($_SESSION['dungeon']);` and `var_dump($GenerateQueue[0])` Copy the results and paste it at https://eval.in And then come back to share the link here.

Comment: This tweaked function works..but has hard coded values:

Comment: @DavidWhite Hard-Coding is not best Practice...  it is not in your best interest... unless it is a code nobody would ever touch again (which is doubtful)... what does your var dump say???